# (excel) Using COUNTIFS with OR

Tags: excel-formula

I hope that someone can offer a solution to the following formula.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2[ColumnA],$AE$16,Table2[ColumnC],$A18,Table2[Date1],"<"&Table2[Date2],Table2[Date2],BLANK))
```

I want a count of matching values but for the last 2 I want to be an OR instead of what is presently there which I assume operates as an AND.

Specifically count if Date1 is less than Date2 or if Date2 is a Blank cell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't compare a whole column to another whole column in Countifs like this `Table2[Date1],"<"&Table2[Date2]`. Describe your complete logic in words. Edit your question to do that. Post a data sample and mock up the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a additional column it will work easily:
Column A & B have your data, column C contain `x` if data2 is empty or `>` for comparision. Formula in column C is `=IF(B2="","x",IF(A2>B2,">",""))`. Your result is delivered in cell E2 with formula `=COUNTIF(C:C,"=?")`

Formulas are translated from german Excel, i hope they will work fine.

[image: Screenshot Excel]